# Python: pack column values in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am still a beginner in python and would like to know how to pack the column values in a list. The values should be separated with a comma.

My previous code:

```
file = open("test1.txt")

grade_list = []

for file_line in file.readlines():
    file_elements_line = file_line.split()
    grade = file_elements_line[2]
    grade_list = grade
    print(grade_list)
```

test.txt looks like:

```
Nr   Name     Grade
2    Max      5.7
5    Linda    6.9
6    Lena     8.0
10   Daniel   4.5
11   Michelle 9.1
```

My output should look like this:

```
[5.7, 6.9, 8.0, 4.5, 9.1]
```

Unfortunately, I didn't get to the solution. Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

```
grade_list = []
with open ('test.txt') as file:
    next(file)
    for file_line in file.readlines():
        file_elements_line = file_line.split()
        grade = file_elements_line[2]
        grade_list.append(grade)

print(grade_list)
```

1. you can use the [`next`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/next) function to skip the first line(in your case, the column name).
2. you need to append to the list and only at the end print it.

Answer (score 2):

Flexibly with [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) object:

```
import csv

with open('test.txt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, skipinitialspace=True, delimiter=' ')
    next(reader)
    grades = [float(row[2]) for row in reader]
    print(grades)
```

The output:

```
[5.7, 6.9, 8.0, 4.5, 9.1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two errors in your code.
1) You need to append to the list, not assign.
2) print should be out of for loop.

```
file = open("test1.txt")

grade_list = []

for file_line in file.readlines():
    file_elements_line = file_line.split()
    grade = file_elements_line[2]
    grade_list.append(grade)

print(grade_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the working solution:

1.Instead of assigning append to array.

2.Pop the first "Grade" element.

```
file = open("test1.txt")

grade_list = []

for file_line in file.readlines():
    file_elements_line = file_line.split()
    grade = file_elements_line[2]
    grade_list.append(grade)
grade_list.pop(0)
print(grade_list)
#['5.7', '6.9', '8.0', '4.5', '9.1']
```